Communication link issue between my app and Mysql using eks cluster
My application worked when I deployed using docker containers but using eks cluster i couldn't build the artefact it gives this error message: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException:
Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
MySpringBootAa23vVotingAppFinalApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Fa...
[
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project MySpring_Boot_aa23v_VotingApp_Final: There are test failures.
Deployed Mysql as pods with SVC. They are running but I tried to build my artefact by amending my application properties with my dB credentials but it keeps give the error message when I use maven to build.
